# Reporting on calls that have been made against a lead?

Tags: reporting

I am trying to write a report that shows me the calls that have been made against a lead. I can only achieve this with all activities, but I want to just show the calls, but I cannot see the type field for some reason!
Tia.

Comment: which report type are you using for the report?

Comment: I am using a custom report type. When I use the standard report Activities with Leads, then it works, but I need to include another object, so I had to make a custom report type. Any ideas how to add the type field?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a current platform limitation.

There's an official workaround described here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004232&language=en_US

And an idea to vote for here:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrFZAA0

Same question was also asked earlier, so some background info here:
[Can Activity Type standard field be added to custom report type?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11600/can-activity-type-standard-field-be-added-to-custom-report-type)